# How to declare an object that is a list of lists of a generic type

Tags: c#, list, generics, nested-lists

Is it possible to declare an object that is  is a **list of** *lists of a generic types*.
So a little like `private List<List<T>> outerList = new List<List<T>>();` but a statement that actually compiles.

I **do not** want to use dynamics like so: `private List<List<dynamic>> list2 = new List<List<dynamic>>();` as I would like type safety.

I'd kind of like to be able to:

```
foreach(List<T> innerList in outerList)
{
    foreach(T item in innerList)
    {
        doSomethingTo(item);
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to declare a class that inherits from the `List<List<T>>`

---

**EDIT:**

I probably should have been clearer. The inner lists must be able to have different types. so one inner list may be `List<string>` and another `List<int>`

---

**FURTHER EDIT**:

Following **@ErikE**'s request the question has been reworded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795240/what-data-structure-can-i-use-to-hold-a-collection-of-multiple-recordsets-with-d).

Comment: Create class of your own....

Comment: Thanks Spawn, really useful there.

Comment: `The inner lists must be able to have different types. so one inner list may be List<string> and another List<int>` this is exacty `List<List<T>>` Or maybe, do you know how generics works in C#?

Comment: Answer very similar with question :)

Comment: @Eser - no, `List<List<T>>` allows you to store multiple lists _of the same type_ - there's no strongly-typed collection that can store both a `List<string>` and a `List<int>`.

Comment: @DStanley Ah yes, if you read this question this way, you are correct..

Comment: @Eser I didn't read it that way initially, only after the OP's edit :)

Comment: _I  do not want to use dynamics ... as I would like type safety_ just doesn't combine with _The inner lists must be able to have different types_. Try to work out the nested loops first, that won't work either.

Comment: @Dib What do you intend to _use_ such a class for?  There may be a data structure that is better suited for your needs than `List`.

Comment: I need some kind of collection that can hold different typed collections. This is to hold the records in multiple recordsets returned from a stored procedure.

Comment: A List of Lists is a horrible way to store recordsets.

Comment: @erike - want to offer a better solution then?

Comment: You need to present the whole use case with examples not just of your data but what you want to accomplish with it. I almost answered your question yesterday and am glad I didn't (because you never stated in your question about how the sublists need to be able to be different types). I can't provide you any kind of wonderful answer without *details*. **Please do NOT modify this question. Ask a completely new question, provide all the details that I've stated, and put a link here.**

Comment: @erike ok will do it tomorrow when i am near a pc.

Comment: Following **@ErikE**'s request the question has been reworded, here:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795240/what-data-structure-can-i-use-to-hold-a-collection-of-multiple-recordsets-with-d

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can define that as a generic class:

```
public class Foo<T> : List<List<T>>
{

}
```

and then have a generic method that processes one of them:

```
public void Process<T>(Foo<T> outerList)
{
    foreach(List<T> innerList in outerList)
    {
        foreach(T item in innerList)
        {
            doSomethingTo(item);
        }
    }
}
```

of course `doSomethingTo` would then need to be generic as well.

> I probably should have been clearer. The inner lists must be able to have different types. so one inner list may be `List<string>` and another `List<int>`

Yes, you should have been clearer.  There's no inheritance relationship between `List<string>` and `List<int>` that would allow you to store them in a single type-safe outer collection.  You would have to resort to `List<object>` or `List<dynamic>`, or find a different data structure that meets your needs.

Comment: I probably should have been clearer. The inner lists must be able to have different types. so one inner list may be List<string> and another List<int>

Comment: You would need to pass two parameters to the method one for each type.

Comment: At compile time, everywhere you see a generic type, it is replaced with whatever type is provided by the caller of the method or constructor of the class. So every one of the lists within the outer list is of that type, since the outer list is of type `List<T>` where T is replaced at compile time.

Comment: Damn, well that has "shot the fox" then.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a `List<List<T>>` that its `T` could be variable in each item. For example if `T=string` then your list is `List<List<string>>` and you can not have any `List<int>` in your top list.

The list you can use is `List<List<object>>` and the thing that will help you to be typed when working with list, is `Cast<T>` method like this:

```
var list = new List<List<object>>();

var intList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var stringList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

list.Add(intList.Cast<object>().ToList());
list.Add(stringList.Cast<object>().ToList());

var sum = 0;
list[0].Cast<int>().ToList()
        .ForEach(i =>
        {
            sum += i;
        });

var msg = "";
list[1].Cast<string>().ToList()
        .ForEach(s =>
        {
            msg += s;
        });
```

**Benefits:**

- We add items typed: (`List<int>`, `List<string>`)
- We use items typed: (`Cast<int>`, `Cast<string>`)

Comment: That might work for me. Let me try.

Comment: @Dib While it is not perfect, but I think it is a good fit.

Comment: It is looking promising, I'll feed back once complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we recall the times of .NET 1.1, there is also a bunch of classes in System.Collections namespace that almost nobody uses nowadays. With that said you could come with something like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.ArrayList> outerList =
  new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.ArrayList>();
```

Comment: The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance. Instead, we recommend the following:
 - For a heterogeneous collection of objects, use the `List<Object>` (in C#) or `List(Of Object)` (in Visual Basic) type.
 - For a homogeneous collection of objects, use the `List<T>` class.  [(Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I see. In that case in internal implementation of .NET it could eventually just become an alias for `List<object>`.