# What Strongly-Typed Data-Structure can I use to hold a collection of multiple RecordSets with different shape

Tags: c#, data-structures, recordset, strong-typing

At the request of a responder to my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770783/how-to-declare-an-object-that-is-a-list-of-lists-of-a-generic-type), I have been asked to reword the question in an effort to get to the bottom of the actual requirement.

What **Strongly-Typed** Data-Structure can I use to hold a collection of multiple **RecordSets** where each **RecordSet** will contain rows that may be of a different shape to the other **RecordSets**?

This need is driven by the need to handle the data coming back from a **Stored Procedure** via a **DbDataReader**. The **Stored Procedure** may have multiple **RecordSets**, with each **RecordSet** returning different columns and number of columns.

There will be **DTO** classes to represent each **row** of the respective data sets. These are known at compile time. What I need is a data structure that can hold the multiple **RecordSets**, and for each **RecordSet** hold the **DTOs** representing rows returned from the **RecordSet**.

Example Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedure]
    @Id                 INT
,   @Name               VARCHAR(20)
,   @Active             BIT
,   @Price              DECIMAL(10, 4)
,   @UniqueIdentifier   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
,   @Count              TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
    /* First Record Set */
    SELECT 
        @Id AS Id
    ,   @Name AS Name
    UNION
    SELECT
        17 AS Id
    ,   'Bill' AS Name;

    /* Second Record Set */
    SELECT 
        @Name AS Name,
        @Active as Active
    UNION
    SELECT
        'Bill' AS Name
    ,   CAST(0 AS BIT) AS Active;

    /* Third Record Set */
    SELECT
        @UniqueIdentifier   AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,   @Count              AS Count
    UNION
    SELECT
        NEWID() AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
   ,    CAST(10 AS TINYINT) AS Count;
END
```

Example calling code:

```
DbConnection connection = CreateConnection();
CommandBehavior commandBehavior = CommandBehavior.Default;

// Create a command to execute the stored storedProcedure
using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateStoredProcedureCommand(
    procedureName,
    procedureParameters,
    commandTimeout,
    transaction))
{
    // Populate a DataReder by calling the command
    using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(commandBehavior))
    {
        // Iterate through each result set...
        do
        {
            // Process the result set line by line
            while (reader.Read())
            {   
                // Read data into DataStructure
            }

        } while (reader.NextResult());
    }    
}
```

Example DTOs here:

```
internal class MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType2
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public decimal Decimal { get; set; }
}

internal class MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType3
{
    public Guid UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Byte Count { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally I do not want a list of **objects** or **dynamics** but a list of my DTOs for the recordset contents. Hopefully this will better clarify my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes sense to return a `List` containing disparate results. I'd probably create a wrapper class to group your dto objects like below.

```
public class RecordSetContainer
{
    public RecordSetContainer()
    {
        RecordSet1 = new List<MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType1>();
        RecordSet2 = new List<MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType2>();
        RecordSet3 = new List<MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType3>();
    }
    public List<MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType1> RecordSet1 { get; set; }
    public List<MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType2> RecordSet2 { get; set; }
    public List<MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType3> RecordSet3 { get; set; }
}
```

If you wanted to take the db code a step further to make it generic you could do something along these lines.

```
public T CallMultipleRecordSetStoredProcedure<T>(
    params Expression<Func<T, IList>>[] recordSetPropertiesInOrder)
    where T : class, new()
{
    var outputType = typeof (T);
    var output = new T();

    // DbConnection & Command setup hidden 

    var recordSetNumber = 0;
    do
    {
        var outputRecordSetPropertyName =
            ((MemberExpression) recordSetPropertiesInOrder[recordSetNumber].Body).Member.Name;
        var dtoList = (IList) outputType.GetProperty(outputRecordSetPropertyName).GetValue(output);
        var dtoListType = dtoList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var item = Activator.CreateInstance(dtoListType);
            var propertiesToWrite = dtoListType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite);

            foreach (var property in propertiesToWrite)
            {
                property.SetValue(
                    item,
                    Convert.ChangeType(reader[property.Name], property.PropertyType));
            }
            dtoList.Add(item);
        }

        recordSetNumber++;
    } while (reader.NextResult());

    return output;
}
```

Not the prettiest or readable code I admit but it should allow you to call any multi record set stored procedure as long as the property names match the column names. One downside with this code is that while the compiler will enforce you to only select `IList` properties in you expressions it is unable to ensure you pick a generic list (which the method itself actually requires).

For your example case the method would be called as below

```
CallMultipleRecordSetStoredProcedure<RecordSetContainer>(
    rsc => rsc.RecordSet1,
    rsc => rsc.RecordSet2,
    rsc => rsc.RecordSet3);
```

Comment: I am going to base my solution mainly on your solution, but with some of **Reza Aghaei**'s advice too. The code in the **CallMultipleRecordSetStoredProcedure** method of your solution is already quite similar to the actual code I have in my framework for single recordset stored procedures, so will be easiest to adapt.

I am not sure about using Expressions as i am not familiar with using them, but between you and Reza I have enough to work on.

I will post my final solution on here once I have completed it later today.

Comment: I was ending up with a null value for the `dtoList`.  Breaking the line down I did get an instantiated `PropertyInfo` object for the line `PropertyInfo info = outputType.GetProperty(listName);`    

I then realised I was not instantiating the **RecordSet** list in my **RecordSetContainer**. Once that was done, code compiled, ran and my tests started to pass again!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think it's better to keep things simple.

1. You have a stored procedure that returns 3 result sets, so create a model that contains those 3 result sets.
2. To fill your `ResultModel`, its better to use `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`. It make things very simple, very very easier than data reader.

**The code for ResultModel:**

```
public class ResultModel
{
    public List<Type1> List1 { get; set; }
    public List<Type2> List2 { get; set; }
    public List<Type3> List3 { get; set; }
}
```

**And I suppose these are your types:**

```
public class Type1
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
public class Type2
{
    public int B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
public class Type3
{
    public int D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
}
```

**And you can fill your ResultModel, using SqlDataAdapter and DataSet:**

```
public ResultModel GetData()
{
    var connection = @"data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
    var command = "dbo.Procedure";
    var tableAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
    tableAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    tableAdapter.Fill(dataSet); 

    var t1 = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .ToList().Select(row => new Type1
        {
            A = row.Field<int>("A"),
        }).ToList();

    var t2 = dataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .ToList().Select(row => new Type2
        {
            B = row.Field<int>("B"),
            C = row.Field<string>("C")
        }).ToList();

    var t3 = dataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
        .ToList().Select(row => new Type3
        {
            D = row.Field<int>("D"),
            E = row.Field<string>("E"),
            F = row.Field<string>("F")
        }).ToList();

    var result = new ResultModel() { List1 = t1, List2 = t2, List3 = t3 };

    return result;
}
```

**The key points here are:**

- We have a clean and simple `ResultModel`
- Using `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataSet` makes reading multiple result so easy.
- Using `Cast<DataRow>()` enables us to use `Linq` against `DataTable.Rows`
- Using `Field<T>("field")` enables us to get typed value of field

Comment: I think you are correct and I have been over complicating things, and will base my solution *partially* on **your** suggested solution and go for a ResultModel with a typed collection for each RecordSet. However I am not going to use the DataSet you suggest because my current framework is using a **DbDataReader** as per my example calling code. I will use a solution that mixes your approach and that of the solution suggested by*SWW*. I will also make the *ResultModel* implement an empty *interface* as per *Joseph*'s suggestion so it is easy to identify in my calling code.

Comment: I will also likely use the Cast you have suggested but in the form of
    Cast<Type1>().ToList()
    Cast<Type2>().ToList()
... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Having read the original question, and this one, it sounds like you will ultimately end up with a List that contains within it other Lists each with their own type.  As you iterate through the list you'll have no idea of what type to expect for the inner list, as it's variable.  Given this you'll inevitably have to test for the type and then cast it, e.g.

```
foreach(var resultset in resultsets)
{
    if(resultset is MultipleRecordSetStoredProcedureReturnType1)
        //... cast it and do something...
}
```

Given that you'll inevitably have to test for the inner type and cast, even if you could achieve your goal I'm not sure it will serve any purpose in the end. The list may as well just be

```
List<List<Object>>
```

or perhaps

```
List<List<IResultSet>>
```

As per the final example, you could consider defining an Interface for the inner type just to ensure that only objects that inherit from that interface are contained within it.  This may be beneficial even if the interface doesn't define any behaviour and is just a simple declaration.

Comment: I did think it would be list of list of someObject. I must confess i had not thought of using an interface and as it is only the data i am interested in not any behaviour as each dto just represents a row in the result set.

Comment: I guess the question is, how do you intend to iterate over the resultant collection?  It may be worth writing that code out first to discover whether the concept works.  I suspect when you write out the code which would be used to iterate over the list of lists you'll find that you need to ask the type and cast.

Just to add if you were to create a List<List<Object>> and then fill it with strongly typed objects.  You'll still have a degree of strong typing, it's ultimately just the outer list that's not strongly typed, but it can't be because your use case is, "it must contain varying types"!

Comment: Goid point anout the outer list. That may have to be dynamic or object.   Regarding test code I'll try and post my test code tomorrow morning when i am near my pc.

Comment: I am going to take a mix of sWW and Reza's solutions, but will implement an **interface** on the ResultSet so I can quickly detect in my code if the return type is for **multiple** or **single** recordsets. That should mean I can use in essence the same code I already have which handles single recordsets with just a slight switch to handle the multiple recordsets as per the other suggestions.